# Finder freezes from time to time and relaunches when I click on a tab

Tags: finder, macos

I use El Capitan on MBP 2014 Retina. I have tried almost everything already:

1. Logged in as a new user. No joy.
2. Reinstalled El Capitan (in situ) - still happening
3. Logged in on safe mode - no joy
4. Ran ETRECheck and cleaned using malware tools and other means until ETREcheck report got clean (see below)
5. Deleted all sorts of Plist files related to Finder, to quicklook, to preview  - no success
6. Removed Finder cache as well as other caches
7. Tried to pinpoint in the console a message that will give a clue (I have the crash report and can provide but need to make sure it is redacted first and that takes a lot of work so waiting with it)

   ```
   ETREcheck report:
   EtreCheck version: 2.6.6 (226)
   Report generated 02/12/2015, 00:24
   Runtime 1:23
   Download EtreCheck from http://etrecheck.com

   Click the [Click for support] links for help with non-Apple products.
   Click the [Click for details] links for more information about that line.

   Hardware Information: (What does this mean?)
       MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) 
       [Click for Technical Specifications]
       [Click for User Guide]
       MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro11,3
       1 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7 CPU: 4-core
       16 GB RAM Not upgradeable
               BANK 0/DIMM0
               8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
           BANK 1/DIMM0
               8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
       Bluetooth: Good - Handoff/Airdrop2 supported
       Wireless:  en0: 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
       Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 82 - SN = C0134170HJLF9CR93

   Video Information: (What does this mean?)
       Intel Iris Pro
       NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M - VRAM: 2048 MB
           Color LCD 2880 x 1800
           S24B300 1920 x 1080
           S24B300 1920 x 1080

   System Software: (What does this mean?)
       OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 (15B42) - Time since boot: about 12 hours

   Disk Information: (What does this mean?)
       APPLE SSD SM0512F disk0 : (500.28 GB) (Solid State - TRIM: Yes)
           EFI (disk0s1) <not mounted> : 210 MB 
           Recovery HD (disk0s3) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 650 MB 
           Macintosh HD (disk1) / : 499.05 GB (264.07 GB free)
               Core Storage: disk0s2 499.42 GB Online

   USB Information: (What does this mean?)
       VIA Labs, Inc.  USB3.0 Hub         1 TB
           Western Digital My Passport 0830 1 TB
           EFI (disk2s1) <not mounted> : 210 MB 
           CarbonCopy and ElCapitan (disk2s2) /Volumes/CarbonCopy and ElCapitan : 999.18 GB (767.18 GB free)
           Recovery HD (disk2s3) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 650 MB 
           VIA Labs, Inc.  USB3.0 Hub         1 TB
               Western Digital My Passport 0820 1 TB
           EFI (disk3s1) <not mounted> : 210 MB 
           My Passport (disk3s2) /Volumes/My Passport : 999.83 GB (503.63 GB free)
       Burr-Brown from TI USB audio CODEC 
       Apple Inc. iPad 
       Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad 
       Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub 
           Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 

   Thunderbolt Information: (What does this mean?)
       Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus
           CalDigit, Inc. Thunderbolt Station

   Gatekeeper: (What does this mean?)
       Mac App Store and identified developers

   Kernel Extensions: (What does this mean?)
           /Applications/MacX Video Converter Pro.app
       [not loaded]    com.macxdvd.driver.goodSysAudioCapture (1 - SDK 10.10) [Click for support]

           /Applications/Toast 14 Titanium/Toast Audio Assistant.app
       [not loaded]    com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower (1.6.7 - SDK 10.7) [Click for support]

           /Applications/WiTopia.app
       [not loaded]    com.viscosityvpn.Viscosity.tap (1.0) [Click for support]
       [not loaded]    com.viscosityvpn.Viscosity.tun (1.0) [Click for support]

           /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox
       [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (4.3.30) [Click for support]
       [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (4.3.30) [Click for support]
       [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (4.3.30) [Click for support]
       [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (4.3.30) [Click for support]

           /Library/Extensions
       [not loaded]    com.CalDigit.ThunderboltStationChargingSupport (1 - SDK 10.8) [Click for support]

           ~/Library/Services/ToastIt.service/Contents/MacOS
       [not loaded]    com.roxio.TDIXController (2.0) [Click for support]

   Launch Agents: (What does this mean?)
       [loaded]    com.hp.StatusMonitor.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist [Click for support]

   Launch Daemons: (What does this mean?)
       [loaded]    com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.adobe.fpsaud.plist [Click for support]
       [running]    com.bombich.ccchelper.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.malwarebytes.MBAMHelperTool.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.microsoft.autoupdate.helpertool.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.tunabellysoftware.TGFanHelper.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    net.witopia.WiTopiaHelper.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    org.virtualbox.startup.plist [Click for support]

   User Launch Agents: (What does this mean?)
       [loaded]    com.adobe.ARM.[...].plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    com.nchsoftware.classicftp.schedule.LikeSurvey.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    uk.co.canimaansoftware.clamxav.clamscan.plist [Click for support]
       [loaded]    uk.co.canimaansoftware.clamxav.freshclam.plist [Click for support]

   User Login Items: (What does this mean?)
       Dropbox    Application  (/Applications/Dropbox.app)

   Other Apps: (What does this mean?)
       [running]    N4RA379GBW.com.busymac.busycal2.alarm
       [loaded]    com.adobe.Reader.99872
       [running]    com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000002.AdobeReader
       [running]    com.busymac.busycal2.105952
       [running]    com.etresoft.EtreCheck.317472
       [loaded]    com.fiplab.MemoryCleanHelper
       [running]    com.fiplab.memoryclean.30752
       [running]    com.getdropbox.dropbox.112352
       [running]    com.microsoft.Excel.32352
       [running]    com.microsoft.Word.116832
       [running]    com.microsoft.autoupdate.fba.207712

   Internet Plug-ins: (What does this mean?)
       Flip4Mac WMV Plugin: Version: 3.3.6.2   - SDK 10.7 [Click for support]
       FlashPlayer-10.6: Version: 19.0.0.245 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
       QuickTime Plugin: Version: 7.7.3
       Flash Player: Version: 19.0.0.245 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
       CouponPrinter-FireFox_v2: Version: 1.1.10 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
       Default Browser: Version: 601 - SDK 10.11
       Silverlight: Version: 5.1.40728.0 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
       JavaAppletPlugin: Version: Java 8 Update 66 build 17 Check version

   User internet Plug-ins: (What does this mean?)
       WebEx64: Version: 1.0 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]

   Safari Extensions: (What does this mean?)
       Save to Pocket
       uBlock

   3rd Party Preference Panes: (What does this mean?)
       Flash Player  [Click for support]
       Flip4Mac WMV  [Click for support]
       Java  [Click for support]
       Perian  [Click for support]

   Time Machine: (What does this mean?)
       Skip System Files: NO
       Mobile backups: ON
       Auto backup: YES
       Volumes being backed up:
           Macintosh HD: Disk size: 499.05 GB Disk used: 234.98 GB
       Destinations:
           My Passport [Local] 
           Total size: 999.83 GB 
           Total number of backups: 63 
           Oldest backup: 13/05/2015, 12:44 
           Last backup: 02/12/2015, 00:02 
           Size of backup disk: Adequate
               Backup size 999.83 GB > (Disk used 234.98 GB X 3)

           TimeMachine USA [Local] 
           Total size: 600.00 GB 
           Total number of backups: 15 
           Oldest backup: 02/10/2015, 01:08 
           Last backup: 23/11/2015, 13:49 
           Size of backup disk: Too small
               Backup size 600.00 GB < (Disk used 234.98 GB X 3)

   Top Processes by CPU: (What does this mean?)
            8%    WindowServer
            4%    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent(9)
            2%    kernel_task
            2%    fontd
            1%    Safari

   Top Processes by Memory: (What does this mean?)
       1.23 GB    kernel_task
       1.07 GB    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent(9)
       328 MB    Finder
       279 MB    WindowServer
       262 MB    Safari

   Virtual Memory Information: (What does this mean?)
       6.39 GB    Free RAM 
       9.60 GB    Used RAM (5.41 GB Cached)
       0 B    Swap Used 

   Diagnostics Information: (What does this mean?)
       Dec 2, 2015, 12:20:57 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-02-002057_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 11:53:48 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-235348_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 10:01:47 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-220147_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 08:59:22 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-205922_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 08:34:54 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-203454_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 05:49:12 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-174912_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 04:45:44 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-164544_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 03:21:35 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-152135_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 11:48:22 AM    Self test - passed
       Dec 1, 2015, 11:39:43 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-113943_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 10:05:05 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-100505_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 08:32:37 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-083237_[redacted].crash
       Dec 1, 2015, 07:28:44 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-12-01-072844_[redacted].crash
       Nov 30, 2015, 05:59:50 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-11-30-175950_[redacted].crash
       Nov 30, 2015, 04:29:11 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-11-30-162911_[redacted].crash
       Nov 30, 2015, 12:27:43 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/PluginProcess_2015-11-30-122743_[redacted].crash
       Nov 29, 2015, 12:30:39 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2015-11-29-123039_[redacted].crash
   ```

Comment: Did you actually re-install OS X 10.11 or did you run the upgrade from OS X 10.10?  I suggest creating a bootable [USB flashdrive install](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/09/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-usb-install-drive/) of OS X 10.11 and doing a clean install.

Comment: At first I upgraded from Yosemite. When I started having the problems with Finder I logged in through the Command-R and reinstalled El-Capitan

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole lot of stuff in there I'd uninstall & test again, then add back one at a time until you find which it might be.

This because I know it causes issues…
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower

and these for various reasons...
com.fiplab.memoryclean [I wouldn't put anything like this back again after testing]
com.busymac.busycal2
com.macxdvd.driver.goodSysAudioCapture
com.roxio.TDIXController
com.tunabellysoftware.TGFanHelper.plist
com.nchsoftware.classicftp.schedule.LikeSurvey.plist
net.witopia.WiTopiaHelper.plist
com.viscosityvpn.Viscosity.tap

I'd also be inclined to temporarily remove both ClamXav & Malwarebytes, just in case they're fighting each other.

Comment: It's usually never a good idea to run two malware applications on the same system.

Comment: Thanks. The problem existed before I downloaded and strated to use Malwarebytes. I will remove it however now that I cleaned the laptop.